# Passing the EditText to another activity it is showing me anything

Tags: android, xml, android-intent

I have an edit text in xml which name and when write a name or something thank opens a button which I am going to click and then this clicked button getting me in another activity but there I need to paste what I have wrote in MainActivity in the EditText.

This is my code.

```
Button btnSearch;
public EditText searchPlugin;

searchPlugin = findViewById(R.id.etSearch);    
btnSearch = findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
        btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivitySearchEngine.class);
                String test = searchPlugin.getText().toString();
                intent.putExtra("TextBox", test);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

This is the another Activity

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_result);
Intent i = new Intent(ActivitySearchEngine.this, MainActivity.class);
String text = i.getStringExtra("TextBox");


searchPlugin = findViewById(R.id.etSearch);
webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
searchPlugin.setText(text);
```

This is the xml of Main Activity for EditText and Button which is send to another activity

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/etSearch" android:imeOptions="actionGo|flagNoExtractUi" style="@style/SearchEditText.MainSearch" />
<Button android:id="@+id/btnSearch" style="@style/ButtonSearch" />
```

This is the xml of the expected `EditText`

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/etSearch" style="@style/SearchEditText.MainSearch"/>
<ImageButton android:id="@id/btnClearSearch" style="@style/ImageButtonClose" />
<ImageButton android:id="@id/imgBtnStopLoad" style="@style/ImageViewStopLoad" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In second activity instead of this

```
Intent i = new Intent(ActivitySearchEngine.this, MainActivity.class);
String text = i.getStringExtra("TextBox");
```

Write this

```
String text = getIntent().getExtras().getString("TextBox");
```

And for show google in webView use this

```
webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/search?q=" + text);
```

Comment: And how to pass here the text
`webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/search?"  + text);`
But is it not working
But your answer for passing the string it is working

Comment: @Spritzig this is another question .check the edited answer

Comment: I have asked a question in SO do you have time to check it ?
Here is the link.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55987483/adding-a-new-drawable-it-is-changing-the-icons-of-the-parsed-xml

Comment: @Spritzig sure i will check tomarow

Answer (score 3):

In your second activity :

```
String text = getIntent().getExtras().getString("TextBox");
```

Answer (score 2):

On the second activity, you need to retrieve the text by doing the following:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_result); //after this
    Bundle arguments = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    String yourString = arguments.getString("TextBox");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

in your ActivitySearchEngine instead of this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(ActivitySearchEngine.this, MainActivity.class)
String text = i.getStringExtra("TextBox");
```

try this:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
String text = i.getStringExtra("TextBox");
```

in your case, you weren't getting the previous intent, you were just creating a new one that would take you back, and that intent didn't have any extras in it. What I did instead is to fetch the original intent and then get the data.

Answer (score 2):

You want to get the intent that called the activity with the following:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
```

Then you want to get the Bundle of extras from that intent that was passed:

```
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
```

From there you can get your string you passed along with the correct key:

```
extras.getString("TextBox", "This is the default value in case the string extra is null");
```

Answer (score 2):

In this line

`Intent i = new Intent(ActivitySearchEngine.this, MainActivity.class);`

You are creating a new intent instead of the one you've passed to the second activity. So just replace with

`Intent i = getIntent();`

And that way you are actually getting the passed Intent which you are interested in getting the extra from it.