# Adding a new drawable it is changing the icons of the parsed xml

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, xml-parsing

I am facing with a problem which happens only when I add new drawable.
I have a parsed `xml` to `Fragment` the `icon` is set like `int`.
If I add new drawable then it chooses random drawables to show the icons for the parsed `xml`.
I have an `Adapter` for the `RecyclerListView`.
A `Pojo` class and `DB` which extends `SQLiteOpenHelper`.
If I clear the cache and Storage then it back to normal, 
or if I delete the new added drawable it returns back to normally.
Can someone help me to know why it is affecting to change the icons.
I have tried to clean project and rebuild the same.
Invalidate cache and restart but still the same.

Below you can find the code and below the code two pictures of the problem.

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

private static final int ITEM_TYPE_ONE = 0;
private static final int ITEM_TYPE_TWO = 1;
private final Handler handler = new Handler();
private final ArrayList<Bookmark> arrayList;
private final String BASE_URL = "https://besticon-demo.herokuapp.com/icon?url=";
private final Context context;

public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Bookmark> arrayList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.arrayList = arrayList;
}


@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = null;
    if (viewType == ITEM_TYPE_ONE) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.grid_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    } else if (viewType == ITEM_TYPE_TWO) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.add_bookmark, parent, false);
        return new ButtonViewHolder(view);
    } else {
        return null;
    }

}
 public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final int itemType = getItemViewType(position);
    final Bookmark bookmark = this.arrayList.get(position);
    if (itemType == ITEM_TYPE_ONE) {
        final ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) holder;
        RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
        BookmarkDB bookmarkDB = new BookmarkDB(context);
        String imageUrl = BASE_URL + arrayList.get(position).getSearchUrl() + "&size=32";
        int resID = context.getResources().getIdentifier(String.valueOf(arrayList.get(position).getIcon()), "drawable", context.getPackageName());
        if (resID == 0) {
            Glide.with(context)
                    .load(imageUrl)
                    .apply(requestOptions
                            .placeholder(R.drawable.default_favicon)
                      .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.AUTOMATIC)
                            .fitCenter())
                    .into(viewHolder.tvIcon);
        } else {
            viewHolder.tvIcon.setImageResource(resID);
             String imageName = context.getResources().getResourceName(resID);
            Log.d("getIcons", imageName); // This is the log.
    } else if (itemType == ITEM_TYPE_TWO) {
        ButtonViewHolder buttonViewHolder = (ButtonViewHolder) holder;
        buttonViewHolder.imgButton.setImageResource(arrayList.get(position).getIcon());
    }
}
   class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    final ImageView tvIcon;

    ViewHolder(@NonNull final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tvIcon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
    }
}
```

The `Bookmark.db`

```
public class BookmarkDB extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final String DBNAME = "bookmarks.db"; // The name of the database file
private static final int DBVERSION = 1;  // The Database version

public static final String TBL_BOOKMARK = "bookmark";
private static final String COL_ID = BaseColumns._ID; // equates to _id
private static final String COl_NAME = "name";
private static final String COl_HIDDEN = "hidden";
private static final String COL_ICON = "icon";
private static final String COL_NATIVEURL = "nativeurl";
private static final String COL_SEARCHURL = "searchurl";

private final SQLiteDatabase mDB;
Context mContext;

public BookmarkDB(Context context) {
    super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
    mDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    // The SQL to be used to create the table
    String crt_bookmark_tbl_sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TBL_BOOKMARK + "(" +
            COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COl_NAME + " TEXT, " +
            COl_HIDDEN + " INTEGER, " +
            COL_ICON + " TEXT, " +
            COL_NATIVEURL + " TEXT," +
            COL_SEARCHURL + " TEXT" +
            ")";
    db.execSQL(crt_bookmark_tbl_sql); // CREATE THE TABLE

}


@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP IF TABLE EXISTS " + DBNAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

public void updateName(String newName, int id, String oldName) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "UPDATE " + TBL_BOOKMARK + " SET " + COl_NAME +
            " = '" + newName + "' WHERE " + COL_ID + " = '" + id + "'" +
            " AND " + COl_NAME + " = '" + oldName + "'";
    db.execSQL(query);
}

public void addBookmark(long id, String name, boolean hidden, String icon, String nativeurl, String searchurl) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

    cv.put(COl_HIDDEN, hidden);
    cv.put(COl_NAME, name);
    cv.put(COL_ICON, icon);
    cv.put(COL_NATIVEURL, nativeurl);
    cv.put(COL_SEARCHURL, searchurl);
    mDB.insert(TBL_BOOKMARK, null, cv);

    // uses the convenience insert method that builds the SQL
}

public ArrayList<Bookmark> getAllBookmarks() {
    ArrayList<Bookmark> rv = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor csr = mDB.query(TBL_BOOKMARK, null, null, null, null, null, null);

    while (csr.moveToNext()) {
        Bookmark b = new Bookmark();
        b.setId(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_ID)));
        int Icon = csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_ICON));
        String name = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COl_NAME));
        String searchUrl = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_SEARCHURL));
        b.setIcon(Icon);
        b.setName(name);
        b.setSearchUrl(searchUrl);
        b.setViewType(csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(COl_NAME)));
        b.setNativeUrl(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_NATIVEURL)));
        rv.add(b);
    }
    return rv;
}
}
```

This is the `.XML` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Bookmarks>
    <Bookmark name="Bing"
 hidden="true"
 icon="bing"
 id="0"
 nativeUrl=""
 searchUrl="https://www.bing.com" />
    <Bookmark
 name="Google"
  hidden="true"
 icon="google"
 id="1" 
nativeUrl=""
 searchUrl="https://www.google.com" />
<Bookmark
    name="Youtube"
    hidden="false"
    icon="youtube"
    id="2"
    nativeUrl="youtube://"
    searchUrl="https://m.youtube.com" />
<Bookmark
    name="Facebook"
    hidden="false"
    icon="facebook"
    id="3"
    nativeUrl="facebook://"
    searchUrl="https://m.facebook.com" />
<Bookmark
    name="Twitter"
    hidden="false"
    icon="twitter"
    id="4"
    nativeUrl=""
    searchUrl="https://mobile.twitter.com/" />
</Bookmarks>
```

Fragment of `RecyclerView`

```
public class FragmentBookmark extends Fragment {
    private final ArrayList<Bookmark> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    private MyAdapter myAdapter;
    private View paramView;
    private RecyclerView myRecyclerView;
    private BookmarkDB mDB;
    private Context mContext;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        mContext = context;
        mDB = new BookmarkDB(mContext);
        mDB.getAllBookmarks();
        buildBookmarkArrayListfromDB();
        loadBookMarksFromXML();
    }

    @Nullable
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        paramView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bookmark, container, false);
        myRecyclerView = paramView.findViewById(R.id.myRecyclerView);
        // myRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mContext));
        myRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(mContext, 4));
        myRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        myAdapter = new MyAdapter(mContext, arrayList);
        myRecyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

        myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        Bookmark bookmark = new Bookmark();
        bookmark.setViewType(1);
        bookmark.setIcon(R.drawable.add_new_bookmark_icon);
        arrayList.add(bookmark);
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setFragmentBookmarkListener(new MainActivity.FragmentBookmarkListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                assert getFragmentManager() != null;
                FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.detach(FragmentBookmark.this).attach(FragmentBookmark.this).commit();
            }
        });

        return paramView;
    }

    private void loadBookMarksFromXML() {

        // MAY WISH TO ONLY DO THIS ONCE as bookmarks would be loaded OTHERWISE DELETE LINE BELOW
        if (DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(mDB.getWritableDatabase(), BookmarkDB.TBL_BOOKMARK) > 0)
            return;
        try {
            XmlResourceParser xpp = getResources().getXml(R.xml.bookmarks);
            while (xpp.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                if (xpp.getEventType() == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                    if (xpp.getName().equals("Bookmark")) {
                        Bookmark bookmark = new Bookmark();
                        bookmark.setName(xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "name"));
                        bookmark.setSearchUrl(xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "searchUrl"));
                        bookmark.setNativeUrl(xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "nativeUrl"));
                        bookmark.setId(xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "id"));
                        int drawableResourceId = getResources().getIdentifier(xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "icon"), "drawable", mContext.getPackageName());
                        bookmark.setIcon(drawableResourceId);
                        bookmark.setViewType(0);

                        if (bookmark.getId() == null) {
                            bookmark.setId("1");
                        }
                        mDB.addBookmark(
                                Long.valueOf(bookmark.getId()),
                                bookmark.getName(),
                                bookmark.getViewType() > 0,
                                String.valueOf(bookmark.getIcon()),
                                bookmark.getNativeUrl(),
                                bookmark.getSearchUrl()
                        );
                    }
                }
                xpp.next();
            }
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void buildBookmarkArrayListfromDB() {
        arrayList.clear();
        arrayList.addAll(mDB.getAllBookmarks());
        Bookmark bookmark = new Bookmark();
        bookmark.setViewType(1);
        bookmark.setIcon(R.drawable.add_new_bookmark_icon);
        arrayList.add(bookmark);
    }
```

This is the `Pojo.class`

```
public class Bookmark implements Parcelable, Comparable, Comparator<Bookmark> {
public static final Creator<Bookmark> CREATOR = new Creator<Bookmark>() {
    @Override
    public Bookmark createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Bookmark(in);
    }

    @Override
    public Bookmark[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Bookmark[size];
    }
};
private String name;
private String id;
private String nativeUrl;
private String searchUrl;
private String hidden;
private long db_id;
private int icon;
private int viewType;

private Bookmark(Parcel in) {
    name = in.readString();
    id = in.readString();
    nativeUrl = in.readString();
    searchUrl = in.readString();
    db_id = in.readLong();
    icon = in.readInt();
    viewType = in.readInt();
    hidden = in.readString();
}

public Bookmark() {
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getIcon() {
    return icon;
}

public void setIcon(int icon) {
    this.icon = icon;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
    this.db_id = Integer.parseInt(id);
}

public String getNativeUrl() {
    return nativeUrl;
}

public void setNativeUrl(String nativeUrl) {
    this.nativeUrl = nativeUrl;
}

public String getSearchUrl() {
    return searchUrl;
}

public void setSearchUrl(String searchUrl) {
    this.searchUrl = searchUrl;
}

public int getViewType() {
    return viewType;
}

public void setViewType(int viewType) {
    this.viewType = viewType;
}

public String getHidden() {
    return hidden;
}

public void setHidden(String hidden) {
    this.hidden = hidden;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Bookmark{" +
            "name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", id='" + id + '\'' +
            ", nativeUrl='" + nativeUrl + '\'' +
            ", searchUrl='" + searchUrl + '\'' +
            ", hidden='" + hidden + '\'' +
            ", db_id=" + db_id +
            ", icon=" + icon +
            ", viewType=" + viewType +
            '}';
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Object o) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(name);
    dest.writeString(id);
    dest.writeString(nativeUrl);
    dest.writeString(searchUrl);
    dest.writeLong(db_id);
    dest.writeInt(icon);
    dest.writeInt(viewType);
    dest.writeString(hidden);
}

@Override
public int compare(Bookmark o1, Bookmark o2) {
    return 0;
}
}
```

This is layout of  `Fragment`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:overScrollMode="never">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/myRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

I have created a LogCat to show what it takes this is the result.

**Right way**

```
drawable/youtube
drawable/facebook
drawable/twitter
```

**After add drawable or vector asset or image**

```
drawable/wiki
drawable/facebook
drawable/trash
```

[image: Right way of showing icons]
[image: When add new drawable]

Comment: If I'm following your description correctly, it's because you're storing the icons in the database as their numerical resource IDs. When you add (or remove, or change) a drawable in your resources, and then rebuild, it's very likely that the drawables will not have the same numerical IDs that they did previously. The simplest fix would probably be to just store the icons' names, rather than their numerical IDs.

Comment: @MikeM. Yes you are right the icons are saved in the database as int. Can you provide an answer for this what you said the simplest fix ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling `String.valueOf(bookmark.getIcon())` to store the icon in your database. As the icon is an `int` representing the resource, this stores the resource id as a string. The issue now is that resource ids are not stable and might change any time you create a new APK. Therefore it works while you don't update the app, but starts failing after.

Instead you should store the name of the res and keep these stable. You're already using the name with your XML data, so I'd assume that's your goal anyhow.

```
mDB.addBookmark(
        Long.valueOf(bookmark.getId()),
        bookmark.getName(),
        bookmark.getViewType() > 0,
        iconName(bookmark.getIcon()),
        bookmark.getNativeUrl(),
        bookmark.getSearchUrl()
);

String Icon = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_ICON));
b.setIcon(iconRes(Icon));
```

Now you only need to implement the mapping from name to id.

```
String iconName(int icon) {
    return getResources().getResourceEntryName(icon);
}

int iconRes(String icon) {
    return getResources().getIdentifier(icon, "drawable", mContext.getPackageName())
}
```

Also you need to unset `mContext` on detach or don't store it and use `getContext()` or `requireContext()` instead. Of course you'd have to check for null if you use it in some background operation.

```
@Override
public void onDetach() {
    mContext = null;
    super.onDetach();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to do `myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` after your arrayList adding work in the  FragmentBookmark:

```
 Bookmark bookmark = new Bookmark();
 bookmark.setViewType(1);
 bookmark.setIcon(R.drawable.add_new_bookmark_icon);
 arrayList.add(bookmark);
 myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

BTW:The xml parse work and database operations should generally be handled asynchronously.

Updated：Change your the type `icon` field in Bookmark from int to String,and modify some code in `loadBookMarksFromXML`,from

```
int drawableResourceId = 
getResources().getIdentifier(
        xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "icon"), "drawable",mContext.getPackageName());
bookmark.setIcon(drawableResourceId);
```

to

```
bookmark.setIcon(xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "icon"));
```

change some code in `onBindViewHolder` in class `MyAdapter`,from:

```
int resID = context.getResources().getIdentifier(String.valueOf(arrayList.get(position).getIcon()), "drawable", context.getPackageName());
```

to

```
int resID = context.getResources().getIdentifier(arrayList.get(position).getIcon()), "drawable", context.getPackageName());
```

You can easily fix other errors caused by changing the `icon` field's type and run again,let me know the result.Thx.

Comment: It is the same problem.

Comment: The code you provided does not look complete. Please provide the full code.

Comment: I have added more code including the `Pojo.class` I have forgotten to add that and I have added the complete `DB` for this.

Comment: "If I add new drawable then it chooses random drawables to show the icons for the parsed xml." I have seen two places you've added the new bookmark icon item in FragmentBookmark,one is in buildBookmarkArrayListfromDB method,the other is in onCreateView,which one do you mean?

Comment: the bookmark icon which is added to the FragmentBookmark it is the second view which has only the Plus button.

Comment: For the moment this is working but I need to test if it all works fine.

Answer (score 2):

For storing image to sqlite or any other local database you must store name of variable(i do this when use local database maybe there is better way)

So when you want to store drawable

Use this code

```
bookmark.setIcon("add_new_bookmark_icon");//don't forget to change icon to String in bookmark
```

Instead of this

```
bookmark.setIcon(R.drawable.add_new_bookmark_icon);//you use this in onViewCreate and buildBookmarkArrayListfromDB
```

Now when you want show drawable from database use this code

```
int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("", "drawable", getPackageName());
Drawable yourImage = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,resourceId);
imageView.setImageDrawable(yourImage);
```

Note

You must change all place use setIcon or getIcon and all code you use icon as int like in `getAllBookmarks` -> `csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_ICON)` and others

I do this several years ago and i don't check it still works. try it and tell me what happens

Comment: You mean to change all from int to String ?

Comment: @Spritzig yes but i think if replace bookmark.setIcon with my code your problem be solve but not sure

Comment: I do have a problem at `FragmentBookmark` at `bookmark.setIcon()` it is return this error `setIcon
(java.lang.String)
in Bookmark cannot be applied to
(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)`

Comment: don't send drawable to bookmark! just when you want show it to imageView use drawable. for this you must post name of drawable image to setIcon. i don't know what icon you must post to bookmark

Comment: Use this bookmark.setIcon("add_new_bookmark_icon");

Comment: Now it is coming the error in this line at adapter `Drawable yourImage = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,resourceId);` with this message `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0`

Answer (score 1):

As the Resource id will be kept on changing at every install or apk generation, it is wise to store the name of the icon resource and fetch it during display time. To do this you can store a string value of the name of the icon(you can also use the same name as of the bookmark, but make sure the drawable of the same name).
Change icon field to String in Database (Bookmark.db) & Pojo.
Remove this line in your Fragment of RecyclerView

```
                int drawableResourceId = getResources().getIdentifier(xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "icon"), "drawable", mContext.getPackageName());
```

Change next line

```
                bookmark.setIcon(xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "name"));
```

In onBindViewHolder in MyAdapter class get icon resource using

```
int iresourceid = getResources().getIdentifier(arrayList.get(position).getIcon(),"drawable",getPackageName());
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should move icons from res folder to assets, then load it with Glide.

```
if (getResources().getAssets().list("").contains("icon.png")) {
    Glide.with(fragment)
        .load(Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/icon.png"))
        .into(imageView);
} else {
    // load from web
}
```